# opencart display "new" on latest products

Tags: opencart

I was wondering if it was at all possible for OpenCart to display a "new" flag/ribbon for the latest products? (on any page) I've been looking for this and I can't seem to find anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using OpenCart 1.5.6.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it for say the 20 newest products, you could call 
`$latest =  $this->model_catalog_product->getLatestProducts(20);` then check if the product id is in $latest. If it is add a field to that product like `$product['new'] = true;` Then you can check for that in the template and add custom markup if it does.